# I have installed decorator, but ImportError: No module named decorator

Tags: python, importerror

I am currently running on 32-bit Windows with 32-bit Python 2.7.14 installed. The decorator 3.4.0 module was installed using `pip install decorator`, but when I try to import decorator, the error message `ImportError: No module named decorator` shows. `pip list` shows that decorator is installed. This code snippet comes from the qgmap 0.1 module which imports decorator inside the *init* file.

I am a beginner programmer, so I do not really know what other information to include in here. Please let me know in the comment section what other information is missing.

Comment: Can you add the terminal stacktrace, how you are importing your module.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\qgmap-0.1\qgmap-example.py", line 3, in <module>
    from qgmap import *
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\qgmap-0.1\qgmap\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import decorator
ImportError: No module named decorator